# Is a woman allowed to marry a man once she was in touch with?

Tags: nikah

I went through something which is not allowed in Islam. I used to chat with guys and then I found a man who totally changed me like Islamically, and I started liking him, but then now I know for women it's not permissible to chat or talk to guys. It's completely forbidden.

So after some time passed by, I went to my dad and explained to him everything, and now I want to make him agree and want to convince him for our marriage. The other party totally agreed, but my dad says it's not allowed in Islam to go through a relation this way.. I explained to him that I'm convinced with what all he said and not going to a wrong path anymore and from something haram I want to come to halaal want to make this halal.

so just want some help so that I can make my father satisfied with what I want.

Comment: The Prophet (PBUH) said :Repentance erases what came before it. Your father has no reference whatsoever to back up his decision.

Comment: Some related Questions http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25896/do-you-think-my-parents-will-let-me-marry-a-future-muslim-man-and-allah-will-he http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26367/fix-a-sinful-relationship-towards-halal http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28467/i-had-premarital-sex-with-my-cousin-now-i-have-questions-about-marriage

Comment: "my dad says it's not allowed in Islam to go through a relation this way" What does _this way_ mean?

Answer (score 2):

> for women it's not permissible to chat or talk to guys. It's completely forbidden.

First of all Islam does not FORBID men/women talking etc. Men and woman are supposed to treat one another with decency and not cross these limits of decency when they see one another.

If you are old enough and mature - that is you are mentally mature enough to get into a contract,  you do have the right to marry  and your parents should listen to you. That said, parents usually think of things that kids can not, because they are thinking that far ahead. So do talk to your parents and try to understand  their side of the argument. If the other party is willing then there is no harm in your parents meeting them at least and having an opportunity to check them out. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you did a good thing by stopping from chat,as it is indeed haram and leads to fitna always. About your father, you have to tell him that in islam, there is no such thing as he is saying (be careful in convincing him about it, as parents normally hate to correct themselves and learn from youngsters).

But first do istkhara before taking this step, that even if this decision is good for you or not.